# AWS localstack SNS endpoint to localhost

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, docker

I am new to docker and localstack. 
I am developing a C# applicatio and am trying to set up AWS SNS endpoint to my local machine (in a certain port say 8585) using localstack in docker. 
I can successfully create topic, subscribe and publish message etc but not receiving any message in my application.

here is the Powershell command I am running to subscribe to the topic

```
Connect-SNSNotification -TopicArn arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:mytopic -Protocol http -Endpoint http://localhost:8585 -EndpointUrl http://localhost:4575
```

I am using Windows 10 machine.

Can anyone please help me giving some guideline and if I am missing anything?

Thanks in advance